# Code Igniter Pagination and URL passed method arguments

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-routing

My problem is that when I press on the pagination link the URL CHANGE and the segment array also so, first I started with this URL:

```
site/argument/argument
```

and when I press the pagination link the URL turn into:

```
site/method/startIndex.
```

Is there a way to use pagination without using the URL query index ?

**EDIT:**

Here is my controller method where I've receive the arguments from the URL:

```
function index ($par1, $par2 = null, $par3 = null)
{       
    $data['records'] = $this->site_model->getRecords($par1, $par2, $par3);

    $this->load->view('main', $data);
}
```

And this is the Model method where I've do the DB query:

```
function getRecords($par1, $par2 = null, $par3 = null )
{
    if (!isset($par2) && !isset($par3)) {
        $where = "lvlOne = '".$par1."'";

    } elseif(isset($par2) && !isset($par3)) {
        $where = "lvlOne = '".$par1."' AND lvlTwo = '".$par2."'";

    } elseif(isset($par2) && isset($par3)) {
        $where = "lvlOne = '".$par1."' AND lvlTwo = '".$par2."' AND lvlThree = '".$par3."'";
    }

    $this->db->from('mph_products');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();


    return $query->result();
}
```

How can I paginate this results? Because I've got conflicts with the pagination library URL

**EDIT:**

I've found a way to do what I've wanted to.
There is a config option of the Pagination Library where you put the suffix of the pagination anchor and you can pass the arguments to it.

$config['suffix'] = "$arg1/$arg2/$arg3";

:D

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want not to see page number in url, but CI Pagination class always add number to link. For more details see [Pagination class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html).

Also you can use [jquery datatable](https://datatables.net/) for client or server pagination.

Comment: I've readed somewhere that there is a way to use the pagination class with AJAX and not seeing the numbers in the url

Comment: Yes, of course you can use Ajax. Please, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This library codeigniter pagination + bootstrap design

```
<?php

class Paginacao
{
public $CI;

function __construct() {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('pagination');

}

function criar($total_rows,$base_url,$per_page=15,$num_links=5)
{
    $paginacao['total_rows'] = $total_rows;

        $paginacao['base_url'] = site_url($base_url);
        $paginacao['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $paginacao['num_links'] = $num_links;

        $paginacao['full_tag_open'] = '<br /><div class="pagination pagination-centered"><ul>';
        $paginacao['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';

        $paginacao['first_link'] = 'Primeira';
        $paginacao['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $paginacao['first_tag_close'] = '<li>';

        $paginacao['last_link'] = 'Ultima';
        $paginacao['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $paginacao['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $paginacao['next_link'] = 'Próximo';
        $paginacao['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $paginacao['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $paginacao['prev_link'] = 'Anterior';
        $paginacao['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $paginacao['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';        

        $paginacao['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $paginacao['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

        $paginacao['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $paginacao['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->CI->pagination->initialize($paginacao);
        $html = $this->CI->pagination->create_links();

    return $html;
}
```

}

Comment: I can't figure out what this does. Can you explain me please?